# Gravitational/electric field with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I used the package `pst-electricfield`, in conjunction with `pspicture`, to obtain a graphical representation of gravitational/electric field (see below). Is it possible to achieve the same results with `tikz`? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Here is the code for `pstricks` and output below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psframe*[linecolor=green!20](-5,-5)(5,5) 
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,griddots=10] 
\psElectricfield[Q={[1 -2 0][-1 2 0]},linecolor=red]
\psEquipotential[Q={[1 -2 0][-1 2 0]},linecolor=blue](-5,-5)(5,5) \psEquipotential[Q={[1 -2 0][-1 2 0]},linecolor=green,Vmin=0,Vmax=0](-5,-5)(5,5)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably the answer is yes, but could you show a picture of this?

Comment: I added the code to your question (you can also edit it of course) and a screenshot of the output. Much better to have it there, you also get better syntax highlighting.

Comment: You can use `pstricks` with xelatex and produce a pdf. Is there any reason to do it with `TikZ`?

Comment: Because i would use some code which i know to implement only in tikz.

Comment: I would be interested in the answer to this as well. I'm using random numbers generated from the pgf package, and pst doesn't allow me to use these values as arguments for drawing field lines. I can successfully create a quiver plot of this, but it's not the field lines, which I would prefer. I would like to add that the documentation for pst does have something, but it's hard to decipher how to effectively use this. The documentation is here: (http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-electricfield/pst-electricfield-docEN.pdf)

Comment: This might be related: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/dipolar-magnetic-field/

Answer (score 5):

It is quite easy in `pgfplots`, which is based on `tikz`, since the plot is made by two analytically defined contour plots as pointed out in the [PDF from @Jeremie's comment](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-electricfield/pst-electricfield-docEN.pdf).

Only the singularity handling is not that easy, I guess the plot suffers from accuracy issues (or maybe my condition for throwing away the singularity points is wrong), so I just filled the background with a circle in the suitable color.

The choice of number of `samples` and `number` of contour levels required a bit of fine tuning for a nice look, and the equations are just hardcoded for the example you gave...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[axis equal image,domain=-4.05:4.05,,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4,samples=40,view={0}{90}]
             % replace missing field lines at singularities
             \fill[blue] (2,0) circle (0.4);
             \fill[blue] (-2,0) circle (0.4);

   \addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=50,labels=false, draw color=blue},thick,]
             {abs(((1)/sqrt((x-2)^2+y^2) - (1)/sqrt((x+2)^2+y^2)))<4 ? ((1)/sqrt((x-2)^2+y^2) - (1)/sqrt((x+2)^2+y^2)) : NaN };

   \addplot3[contour gnuplot={number=18,labels=false, draw color=red},
             thick,
            ]
             {abs(((x-2)/sqrt((x-2)^2+y^2) - (x+2)/sqrt((x+2)^2+y^2)))<10 ? ((x-2)/sqrt((x-2)^2+y^2) - (x+2)/sqrt((x+2)^2+y^2)) : NaN };

 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]