# Accessing pgfplots coordinates for each sample of a plot (quiver plot)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows

Since [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365760/customization-of-quiver-plots-access-to-variables-x-y-u-v) is maybe overloaded and contains too much unnecessary details, I tried to reformulate it into a more condensed and comprehensive form.

The problem is that I want to access the quiver plot coordinates (x,y,u,v) in an own piece of code, in `quiver/after arrow/.code`, oder alternatively in `quiver/before arrow/.code`. The following example does not make sense completely, since one could easily just change u and v vales. However, the problem is exactly the same as in my other question.

In the code, I have added a comment where I try to access the coordinates and where different non-working possibilites are commented out.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal image,enlargelimits=false,clip=false]
      % Reference plot
      \addplot[
               quiver={
                       u=x,v=y,
                      },
               ->,
               samples=5,domain=0:1
              ] {x*x};

              % own plot
      \addplot[
               quiver={
                       u=x,v=y,
                       % draw some other (e.g. orthogonal) arrows here!
                       after arrow/.code={
                                          \draw[blue,dashed,->] (0.5,0.25) -- ($ (0.5,0.25) + (0.25,-0.5)$);
                                          \draw[blue,dashed,->] (1,1) -- ($ (1,1) + (1,-1)$);
        %
        %
        % Things which are not working
        %
        %
                                          %\draw[blue,dashed,->] (x,y) -- ($ (x,y) + (v,-u)$);
                                          %\draw[blue,dashed,->] (\x,\y) -- ($ (\x,\y) + (\v,-\u)$);
                                          %\draw[blue,dashed,->] (\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y) -- ($ (\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y) + (\pgfplots@quiver@v,-\pgfplots@quiver@u)$);
                                         };
                      },
               draw=none,
               samples=5,domain=0:1
              ] {x*x};

   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the design of `quiver` is very inflexible. By the time the arrows are drawn, (x,y) coordinates are stored in `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` and (u,v) coordinates are translated to absolute coordinate. You do not have much choice.

Perhaps you can plot the same function twice with different `quiver`.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal]
      % Reference plot
      \addplot[
               quiver={u=x,v=y},
               ->,
               samples=10,domain=0:1
              ] {x*x};

              % own plot
      \addplot[
               quiver={u=y,v=-x},
               ->,blue,
               samples=10,domain=0:1
              ] {x*x};

   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

## A fragile way to access relative coordinate of (u,v)

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path#1{%
    % remember (x,y) in a robust way
    #1%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@x{\pgf@x}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@y{\pgf@y}%
    % calculate (u,v) in relative coordinate
    \pgfplotsaxisvisphasetransformcoordinate\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v\pgfplots@quiver@w%
    \pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@quiver@u}{\pgfplots@quiver@v}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@u{\pgf@x-\pgfplots@quiver@x}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@v{\pgf@y-\pgfplots@quiver@y}%
    % move to (x,y) and start drawing
    {%
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v}%
    }%
}%

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal]
      \addplot[
               quiver={u=x,v=y,
                 after arrow/.code={
                   \relax{% always protect the shift
                     \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
                     \node[below right]{\tiny$(u,v)=(\pgfplots@quiver@u,\pgfplots@quiver@v)$};
                   }
                 }
               },
               ->,
               samples=10,domain=-1:1
              ] {x*x};
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<del># OK...

The following code modify the internal procedure so that `\pgfplots@quiver@x` is the canvas x-coordinate and `\pgfplots@quiver@u` is the canvas, relative u-coordinate.


    \documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone} 
    \usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

    \begin{document}

    \makeatletter
    \def\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path#1{%
        % remember (x,y) in a robust way
        #1%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@x{\pgf@x}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@y{\pgf@y}%
        % calculate (u,v) in relative coordinate
        \pgfplotsaxisvisphasetransformcoordinate\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v\pgfplots@quiver@w%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@u{\pgfplots@quiver@u-\pgfplots@quiver@x}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@v{\pgfplots@quiver@v-\pgfplots@quiver@y}%
        % move to (x,y) and start drawing
        {%
            \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfplotsqpointxy\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v}%
        }%
    }%

      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal]
          \addplot[
                   quiver={u=x,v=y,
                     after arrow/.code={
                       \relax{% always protect the shift
                         \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
                         \node[below right]{$(u,v)=(\pgfplots@quiver@u,\pgfplots@quiver@v)$};
                       }
                     }
                   },
                   ->,
                   samples=10,domain=0:1
                  ] {x*x};
       \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}

[![][2]][2]</del>

## Disclaimer

Currently `before arrow` and `after arrow` is not used elsewhere in the package. The fact that (u,v) is in absolute coordinate might be changed in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I've tried to explain in the question that this example is only for a simple demonstration of my problem (see the linked question). The problem is that I want to do sthg else than drawing an arrow, and therefore I need the coordinates. Is it somehow possible to acces `\pgf@x` in `before arrow/.code` or `after arrow/.code` or somehow else?

Comment: Maybe I could use normal plot and not quiver, to access x and y for every sample of a table?

Comment: I am currently playing with `\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis` and `\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path`. But they are really tough. I guess you can subtract `x` from `u` (It is `\pgfplotsplothandlersurveypoint@quiver` that makes u-v absolute. Maybe you can modify it)... And yes, because quiver is merely a kind of point-meta.

Comment: If it's easier for normal `addplot`, I could mis-use the `z` coordinate to store the rotation angle I need for the arrows, and use the point-meta value for the scaling and coloring of my arrows... I'll try to look into that.

Comment: @Faekynn Please see my edit.

Comment: It's working so far! :) I will try to transfer this to my other example...

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not to work if i have negative coordinates. e.g. with `domain=-1:1` the arrow at the point (1,1) certainly is not 45degree anymore. And a second thing: `point meta` isn't working any more... Do you have any idea why? I didnt see that you altered something for `meta`...

Comment: @Faekynn I guess I know the reason. Originally the drawing code is `\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{x}{y}}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfplotspointxy{u}{v}}` and notice that `\pgfpoint` and `\pgfplotspointxy` are using different transformation.

Comment: @Faekynn I fixed the code. If there is still some bug please tell me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix! You probably skipped my other point: `point meta` isn't working any more. Simple test case: adding the option `point meta={x},`and in the node text `\color{red}{\pgfplotspointmetatransformed}` But since I did not ask anything about `meta` in this question, I can also ask a new one...

Comment: It seems strange to me, because the original `\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path` doesn't do anything with meta values as well...

Comment: @Faekynn Probably better to ask a new question. So other potential answerers can play with an MWE.

Comment: I thought so, too. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366266/customizing-the-quiver-plot-including-point-meta-values if you are also still interested ;)