# Customizing the quiver plot (including point meta values)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So, after the [brilliant solution of @Symbol1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366065/accessing-pgfplots-coordinates-for-each-sample-of-a-plot-quiver-plot) to my last question, I have a new one on the same topic. 
With the proposed code, which changes the behavior of `\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path`, `point meta` seems not to work anymore...

This has effects on the `mapped color` and `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed`

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path#1{%
    % remember (x,y) in a robust way
    #1%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@x{\pgf@x}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@y{\pgf@y}%
    % calculate (u,v) in relative coordinate
    \pgfplotsaxisvisphasetransformcoordinate\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v\pgfplots@quiver@w%
    \pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@quiver@u}{\pgfplots@quiver@v}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@u{\pgf@x-\pgfplots@quiver@x}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@v{\pgf@y-\pgfplots@quiver@y}%
    % move to (x,y) and start drawing
    {%
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v}%
    }%
}%

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis equal]

      \addplot[
               point meta=x,
               quiver={u=x,v=y,
                 after arrow/.code={
                   \relax{% always protect the shift
                     \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
                     \node[below right]{\tiny\color{mapped color}\pgfplotspointmetatransformed};
                   }
                 }
               },
               ->,
               samples=10,domain=-1:1
              ] {x*x-1};


      \addplot[
               point meta=x,
               quiver={u=x,v=y,
                      every arrow/.append style={%
                        -{Latex[scale length={max(0.1,\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000)}]},mapped color
                      },
               },
               ->,
               samples=10,domain=-1:1
              ] {x*x};
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the unchanged version, scaling and coloring works, for the changed one neither of the two things work.

[image]

For the sake of completion, the original `pgfplots` code which is replaced (I can't see anything about meta values in here?!?)

```
\def\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path#1{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{#1}%
    \pgfplotsaxisvisphasetransformcoordinate\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v\pgfplots@quiver@w
    \pgfpathlineto{%
        \pgfplotsifcurplotthreedim{%
            \pgfplotsqpointxyz\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v\pgfplots@quiver@w
        }{%
            \pgfplotsqpointxy\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v
        }%
    }%
}%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path#1{%
    % remember (x,y) in a robust way
    #1%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@x{\pgf@x}\global\let\pgfplots@quiver@x\pgfplots@quiver@x%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@y{\pgf@y}\global\let\pgfplots@quiver@y\pgfplots@quiver@y%
    % calculate (u,v) in relative coordinate
    \pgfplotsaxisvisphasetransformcoordinate\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v\pgfplots@quiver@w%
    \pgfplotsqpointxy{\pgfplots@quiver@u}{\pgfplots@quiver@v}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@u{\pgf@x-\pgfplots@quiver@x}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@v{\pgf@y-\pgfplots@quiver@y}%
    % move to (x,y) and start drawing
    {%
        \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint\pgfplots@quiver@u\pgfplots@quiver@v}%
    }%
}%

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal]
            \addplot[
                point meta=x,
                quiver={
                    u=x,v=y,
                    every arrow/.append style={%
                        -{Latex[scale length={max(0.1,\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000)}]},mapped color
                    },
                    after arrow/.code={
                        \relax{% always protect the shift
                            \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\pgfplots@quiver@x}{\pgfplots@quiver@y}}%
                            \node[below right]{\tiny\color{mapped color}\pgfplotspointmetatransformed};
                        }
                    }
                },
                ->,samples=10,domain=-1:1
            ]{x*x-1};
            \addplot[
                point meta=x,
                quiver={
                    u=x,v=y,
                    every arrow/.append style={%
                        -{Latex[scale length={max(0.1,\pgfplotspointmetatransformed/1000)}]},mapped color
                    },
                },
                ->,samples=10,domain=-1:1
            ]{x*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Explanation

The main difference of this code and the one in you previous question is that

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@x{\pgf@x}
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@y{\pgf@y}
```

is made into

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@x{\pgf@x}\global\let\pgfplots@quiver@x\pgfplots@quiver@x%
\pgfmathsetmacro\pgfplots@quiver@y{\pgf@y}\global\let\pgfplots@quiver@y\pgfplots@quiver@y%
```

which suggests that the error is introduced by extra grouping. But why is there extra grouping? Well, because when pgfplots encounters

```
\draw[/pgfplots/quiver/every arrow]...
```

the options of the `\draw` is, by convention, affecting only this `\draw`. Hence Ti*k*Z will put this `\draw` in a group. And since `\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path` is thereby put in a group, you cannot see `\pgfplots@quiver@x` from outside (in particular in `after arrow`).

---

By the way, the `#1` of the `\pgfplotsplothandlerquiver@vis@path` is, roughly speaking,

```
\global\pgf@x=\pgf@x
\global\pgf@x=\pgf@y
```

And the analysis above shows the necessity of this.

Comment: That solved all my issues!
See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366284/44467 for my final results of the nicer quiver plot.